# How to add an onclick Event Listener to a created button element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a dynamic MadLibs webpage. On the homepage, a user can choose between 3 stories to create a MadLibs for, and when they click a button, the page changes where they will insert their nouns, adjectives, etc. in text input fields. They must then click a button to replace the original words in the story with the words they input.

The button on the second page I create and append to the page, but for some reason the onclick event listener I want to attach to it that triggers the function to replace the words will not attach to the button element.

Below is the code where I create the button element and append it to the document body. The function I have created that replaces the words in the story is called subWords().

```
          var addb = document.createElement("button");
          addb.innerHTML = "Add Words!";
          addb.id = "addb";
          addb.value = "addb";
          document.body.appendChild(addb);
          document.getElementById("addb").addEventListener('click',subWords);
```

I have tried so many different things, including:

```
addb.onclick = subWords;
```

before I append the button to the body,

```
addb.onclick = function(){subWords};
```

```
addb.onclick = function(){subWords()};
```

```
addb.onclick = function(){subWords;};
```

and just about every other combination of things I can find on this site. None of them are working for me!!

If someone could please help me figure out this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. I've tried everything and nothing works for me. Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of the `subwords` function? When is this particular code executed? Do you see anything in the console when this code runs, or when the button is clicked? Any of this, or similar, information could help answer this question - but as it is it's guesswork at best. Best of all would be for you to include, in your question, *all* relevant code (possibly including HTML), a description of what you expect to happen, and what happens (or doesn't) instead.

Comment: The subwords function is a basic replacement function that uses regex to replace the words in story with the user input. The function works perfectly when I add ```onclick="subWords()"``` to the attribute of the button when I inspect the page.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `document.getElementById("addb").addEventListener('click',subWords)` with `addb.addEventListener('click',subWords)`, and move that line just before `document.body.appendChild(addb)`?

Comment: No that does not work. For some reason any combination of things listed above, including what you just said, will not work at all.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having to guess because, as I alluded to earlier, you haven't given enough information. Last guess before I give up: are you sure `subWords` has been declared as a function before this code runs? You might have to move the declaration to the top of your file/script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what you can do is append to the parent using HTML DOM without creating elemnt.

> ```
> (parentElemnt).innerHTML += `<button value="addb" id="addb" onclick="subWords">Add Words!</button>`;
> ```

The += will append what is inside `` ... Instead of creating and appending and then giving the values, you can do it one line. Select the parent element using DOM and then substitute inside

> (parentElement)

.

Check if this works out and good luck.
I am sorry for not including the code of the best practices. If you could share your entire code I would be happy to check on how to fix without appending to an element.

Lasal.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I was only using the techniques my professor has taught us and never mentioned doing something like this. Thank you!

Comment: Even if this works here, using += with an element's `innerHTML` is very bad practice. Indeed I also hate passing HTML around as strings in the first place. (and an inline `onclick` attribute smells too.) The OP's approach is vastly better than this, I'm still unsure as to why it doesn't work, but some things can be ruled out if this works instead.